# Looking to return certain value based on how many times a value matches across two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've got ID numbers associated with up to two values (SYS-A AND SYS-B) in another column, but each ID could appear could appear multiple times under SYS-A and/or SYS-B. I need Excel to look at each ID and tell me if it is associated with both systems or if it is associated with only one and which system if only one. Could I have the "RESULT" column on another tab as I have one tab with payments by social and the other with the system each ID is associated with? "Result" should be dependent on Tab 1.

TAB 1
ID------SYS
1--------A
1--------A
1--------B
1--------A
2--------B
3--------A
3--------A

TAB 2
ID-----PAYMENT---RESULT
1---------5---------------BOTH
2---------3-----------------B
3---------2-----------------A

Comment: You mean the Result depend of TAB 1

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Are you ok with a helper column next to column SYS?

Comment: Yea, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Ideal:**

1. Adds a column as key to be looked-up, the key is concatenation of ID and SYS;
2. Uses `countif` to check existence of ID+"A" and ID+"B", puts the result into bitmap - bit0 indicates existence of B, bit1 indicates existence of A, resulting in following map: 0 - None, 1 - B, 2 - A, 3 - Both;
3. Uses `lookup` to translate the value 0, 1, 2, 3 into expected text according to above mapping;

**Steps:**

Suppose Table 1 ID 1 is at A2, Table 2 ID 1 is at cell A11:

1. In Table 1, formula of cell C2 is `=A2&B2`, then fill down;
2. In Table 2, formula of C11 is `=(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,A11&"A")<>0)*2+(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,A11&"B")<>0)`, then fill down;
3. In Table 2, formula of D11 is `=LOOKUP(C11,{0,1,2,3},{"NONE","B","A","BOTH"})`, then fill down;

**Example:**

```
ID  SYS KEY
1   A   1A
1   A   1A
1   B   1B
1   A   1A
2   B   2B
3   A   3A
3   A   3A

ID  PAYMENT val RESULT
1   n/a     3   BOTH
2   n/a     1   B
3   n/a     2   A
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution based on SUMPRODUCT, IF & AND functions with a Helper column

[image]

Formula in H4 cell and to be dragged down.

```
=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$13=G4)*($C$4:$C$13="A"),$D$4:$D$13)>=1,SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$13=G4)*($C$4:$C$13="B"),$D$4:$D$13)>=1),"BOTH",IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$13=G4)*($C$4:$C$13="A"),$D$4:$D$13)>=1,"A",IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$13=G4)*($C$4:$C$13="B"),$D$4:$D$13)>=1,"B","Invalid")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in a new TAB
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(('TAB 1'!$A$2:$A$8='TAB 3'!A2)*('TAB 1'!$B$2:$B$8="A"))=COUNTIF('TAB 1'!$A$2:$A$8,'TAB 3'!A2),"A",IF(SUMPRODUCT(('TAB 1'!$A$2:$A$8='TAB 3'!A2)*('TAB 1'!$B$2:$B$8="B"))=COUNTIF('TAB 1'!$A$2:$A$8,'TAB 3'!A2),"B","BOTH"))`

In TAB 1 you have your Data without heading from A2 to B8 for example
In TAB 3 You can copy paste all the ID then remove duplicates starting the ID values from A2 and in B2 paste the formula above